# C# Add 2 comboBox to csv text file

Tags: c#, csv, combobox

Am close with this but it still failing. Just adds combobox1 item many times then changes. Combobox2 gets added correctly for each entry of cbo1.
Also adds the delimiter , at front of line in MyFile.txt
I load this with a split no problem, going back is the trouble
I'm like new real new C#.

```
StreamWriter OutFile = new StreamWriter("MyFile.txt",false);

foreach(object L in comboBox1.Items)
foreach(object M in comboBox2.Items)
{
    string lineoftext1 = (L.ToString());

    string lineoftext2 = (",");

    string lineoftext3 = (M.ToString());

    string joinedText;
    joinedText = String.Join(lineoftext1, lineoftext2, lineoftext3);
    //MessageBox.Show(joinedText);

    OutFile.WriteLine(joinedText);
}

OutFile.Close();
```

Comment: Can you please explain more clearly as to what output you are expecting? Your current code gives different combinations of the items in combo box 1 and combo box 2.

Comment: Yes they are different. One is a name whatever you name it and 2nd box is a registry entry. It shouldnt matter. How to export 2 combobox to txt file with a delimiter. They should sync with each other like Name, Address Type that in google and you don't get anything

Comment: i think what Tejus is saying is that based on what your saying you want,  the code you have given is correct. (i can't see anything wrong with it)  it should return (assuming there are 2 items in each box)  L1,M1  |  L1, M2   | L2,M1 | L2,M2     is this not what you are getting?  if not,  what do you expect to see?

Comment: @veeger, u mean to say, combobox same items are added again and again when post back ?

Comment: When exporting, cbo1 gets added numerous times with cbo2 correct. Then it starts over with cbo1 item 2 and cbo2 adding again. I think it not stepping down to next cbo1 item

Comment: ,__Wow6432NodeComputer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node
,__Wow6432NodeComputer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\BIOS
,__Wow6432NodeComputer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control
,__Wow6432NodeComputer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog

Comment: All on one line but this is what it should look like with my delimiter ,
__Wow6432Node,Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node
__BIOS,Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\BIOS
__Control,Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control
__eventlog,Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog

Comment: Postback is actually sending all the information from client to web server, then web server process all those contents and returns back to the client.

Comment: Just posted the answer below,  having seen your lists above of what your expecting to see,  my answer should be Spot on.   Your passing the lineoftext1 as the separator instead of the comma.   If you had more then 2 this would have become obvious because you would have seen ,__BIOS(key)__BIOS(nextvalue)__BIOS(lastvalue)

Comment: No the delimiter is added at start of output. I stated that as an original problem. In VB6 you would add a Next at the end of processing with the the For. Can't see that in this C#. Original file is 129 lines, exporting this way I get 16641

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OOOOH,  i see the problem,  it's in the way you are handling your strings,  you don't use string.join that way,   you can either join them explicitly like this:

```
joinedText = lineoftext1 + lineoftext2 + lineoftext3;
```

or you need to create something that the join method accepts,  i would use a list,  so the inside of your foreach loop would look like this

```
List<string> mystrings = new List<string>();
mystrings.add(L.ToString());
mystrings.add(M.ToString());

joinedText = String.Join(",", mystrings);
```

alternativly you could leave it how you have it,  but change some values around

```
joinedText = String.Join(lineoftext2, lineoftext1, lineoftext3);
```

The first parameter passed to String.Join is the seperator.  you were passing it the text.

If this doesn't help, then i would want to see your expected output as i mentioned in my comments above.

Edit:   Try this if you want a 1-1  2-2 style

```
int i = 0;

foreach (object M in comboBox1.Items)
        {

            List<string> mystrings = new List<string>();

            mystrings.Add(comboBox2.Items[i].ToString());
            mystrings.Add(M.ToString());

            OutFile.WriteLine(String.Join(",", mystrings));
            i++;

        }
```

just be aware,  this will error if there are different numbers of items in each combobox. (you will get an outside array bounds error)

Comment: You are real close it puts delimiter where it should be but still adding 1st item of cbo1 many times then rinse repeat                      
_Wow6432Node is first item of combobox1                              
__Wow6432Node,Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node
__Wow6432Node,Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\BIOS
__Wow6432Node,Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control
let me try to add the other

Comment: Error 3 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' does not contain a definition for 'add' and no extension method 'add' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' could be found

Comment: so there will always only be item from each combobox?   so like M1, L1   |   M2,L2  |  M3,L3?   The way you have the code written,  it will take the 1st item from the first combo box,  then iterate through the 2nd combobox,  then take the 2nd item from the first combobox and iterate through it,  if you want a 1-1 match,  then take out one of the foreach and use an index instead.

Comment: as for the Error 3,   it's mystrings.Add(whatever)   capital A,  sorry was lazy typing out the answer above >.>

Comment: StreamWriter OutFile = new StreamWriter("MyFile.txt", false);

            int i = 0;

            foreach (object M in comboBox1.Items)
            {

                List<string> mystrings = new List<string>();
                mystrings.Add(comboBox1.Items[i].ToString());
                mystrings.Add(comboBox2.Items[i].ToString());
                mystrings.Add(M.ToString());

                OutFile.WriteLine(String.Join(",", mystrings));
                i++;

            }

            OutFile.Close();

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure , i think in your combobox1, same items are added when a post back is done, so it repeats back to combobox1 even any changes happens in combobox2. If this is your question, you can overcome this by adding your code inside, `if (!IsPostBack)`, something like this,

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
      //write you code here 
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nikerym you got it man I just added combobox1 below
129 lines as was the original 
Thanks M8

```
        StreamWriter OutFile = new StreamWriter("MyFile.txt", false);

        int i = 0;

        foreach (object M in comboBox1.Items)
        {

            List<string> mystrings = new List<string>();
            mystrings.Add(comboBox1.Items[i].ToString());
            mystrings.Add(comboBox2.Items[i].ToString());


            OutFile.WriteLine(String.Join(",", mystrings));
            i++;

        }

        OutFile.Close();
```

Comment: i think your adding the value of combobox 1 twice?   this would come out looking like M1,L1,M1 | M2,L2,M2  etc,   if you want to only have M1,L2  then remove the line mystrings.Add(M.Tostring());  or the mystrings.Add(comboBox1.Items[i].ToString());   .... which you just edited as i typed this ;)